# como consultar banco de dados informado por variável?

Tags: sql-server

Apenas um exemplo de query sql server:

```
SELECT A.name FROM [banco1].sys.procedures as A
```

O que eu preciso é que essa query acima, seja alterada para algo como:

```
SELECT A.name FROM [@nomeBanco].sys.procedures as A
```

Porque assim, vou poder fazer algo como:

```
declare @nomeBanco varchar(50) = "Banco1"
select A.name from [@nomeBanco].sys.procedures as A
```

Obrigado a todos que puderem compartilhar idéias.
Feliz Ano Novo 2021.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que nesse caso você terá que utilizar uma query dinâmica:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max);
set @SQL = N'select A.name from [' + @nomeBanco + '].sys.procedures as A';
execute sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: é uma ideia boa... mas, vou esperar ver se tem mais alguém com algo mais simples.